# Eclipse RCP Automation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am building a RCP Application which is having 5-6 features and I am using tycho to build this application.
Another team develops and deploy 25+ plugins to p2 repository(i.e. URL = http:\oragnaizaion.com\RCP-Application\plugins).
So when tycho builds my application I need to download the application and after launch I need to install these plugins manually from the given p2 repo URL.

So here I am looking for a solution in which I can automatically install these 25+ plugins by providing URL during tycho build of the RCP application. anyone can please help me on this.

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Comment: Can't that repo just be part of your target platform?